# How can I stop the debugger server from pydev?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I am using the pydev remote debugger feature for my application.

When I try to stop the debugger server via the stop button it shows on the console that the server is successfully terminated but it isn't because it is still accepting new connections on its default port (5678).

Do you know how can I stop the server in a reliable way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug -- and it was fixed in the latest version (PyDev 2.2.4), so, please upgrade to the latest version and that should be working already.